# Disable annoying global menu shortcuts

Tags: unity, 14.04, menu, ccsm

I would like to disable Alt+[key] from triggering the global menu categorie on Ubuntu 14.04 (for example the Alt+h combination triggers the help menu). I have unactivated numbers of unity features with dconf and ccsm in order to do that but it still won't work.